# Ruby regex returning unexpected results while matching a string containing \n characters

Tags: regex, ruby

Below is the output from my `irb` console

```
2.3.2 :001 > str = "Whenever ThingA happens\nrepeats: Sunday, Monday and Tuesday\n\n\nDo ThingB"
 => "Whenever ThingA happens\nrepeats: Sunday, Monday and Tuesday\n\n\nDo ThingB"

2.3.2 :002 > str.match(/(.*)\s*(?:repeats)/)
 => #<MatchData "Whenever ThingA happens\nrepeats" 1:"Whenever ThingA happens">

2.3.2 :003 > str.match(/(.*)(?:repeats)/)
 => #<MatchData "repeats" 1:"">
```

Can anybody please help me understand what's going on with the 2nd regex  `/(.*)(?:repeats)/` which is causing it not return the expected result the 1st regex `/(.*)\s*(?:repeats)/` returns?

On [rubular.com](https://rubular.com/) 2nd regex shows following match `1. Whenever ThingA happens\n` which is expected however Ruby's [String#match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-match) returns unexpected results as shown in console output above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot does not match new line characters so it is selecting the character before repeats for the given line, which is nothing. Essentially the same as `/(?=repeats)/` since repeats this the first word on this line.

Adding the `m` flag (make dot match newlines) will solve this for you

```
str.match(/(.*)repeats/m)
#=> #<MatchData "Whenever ThingA happens\nrepeats" 1:"Whenever ThingA happens\n">
```

The reason the first one works is becuase `\s` indicates a whitespace character and that does match the new line `\n` since new line is a whitespace character.

The noncapture group has no impact as pointed out by @CarySwoveland

Comment: ...`str[/.*\nrepeats/]`. Jignesh, note that the non-capture group has no effect.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that is not a MatchData Object and your response will include `"repeats"` where as the noncapture will not when used with `match`

Comment: I don't follow: `str.match(/(.*)repeats/m) #=> #<MatchData "Whenever ThingA happens\nrepeats" 1:"Whenever ThingA happens\n">`.